# 'Open Sans', sans-serif looks different in mac

Tags: html, css

I am using 'Open Sans', sans-serif as font family in my website.But it looks little bit different in mac systems.
[image]

This is how it looks in mac.
And
[image]

This is in other systems.

Comment: share some screenshot

Comment: All systems render fonts slightly differently, because of different techniques for anti-aliasing and other stuff. What exactly is your question?

Comment: how to make mac fonts same as that of other systems@VictorMarchuk

Comment: It would appear, based on the images, you're rendering 2 different **faces** of Open Sans. The top appears to be 700 or 800, the bottom 400.

Comment: faces means?@Scott

Comment: Weight... bold, normal... etc. Top looks like the font weight of 700 or 800, the bottom looks like the font weight of 400.

Comment: Thats ok.My question is why it happens so?And how to make it unique@Scott

Comment: @akhil, the reason why the fonts appear different has been explained by Victor. If you want to make it unique you can use any of the fonts from [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) and use it in your web page like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Those are actually two different fonts. Take a look at the letter "a" in each image. They have different tails.

My guess is you have Open Sans installed on your one computer and not the other computer? The bottom image looks the most like Open Sans so I would guess you may have it installed there. (I'm not saying you need it installed for fonts to work properly, obviously, but having it installed explains why it shows up there and not the other computer)

How are you including the font because it looks like it's not actually getting included properly. If you don't include the font properly, but you set the font in CSS, the computer that has the font installed will show the proper font, but the other computer will show a fallback font.

EDIT:
If you don't have it installed on either device than none of them are in fact Open Sans and they are both fallback fonts. The top image looks like Helvetica to me. Try doing "inspect element" and going to "computed" if you're in Chrome (I'm unfamiliar with a similar way to view this in other browsers, I'm sorry) to see what fonts they're actually producing.